# getElementByID search

Tags: vba, web, getelementbyid

My question concerns searching for an element, titled, an 'input ID' type of element, on a webpage before next part of the code. My code, below, doesn't find the element and just keeps looping.

```
Dim Elem As Object

Do
    Set Elem = Nothing
    Set Elem = document.all.getElementById("XXXXXX")
    DoEvents
Loop While Elem Is Nothing

' Next part of code.
```

Thanks..

Comment: That's probable because your code searches only in TOP level, the element you're looking for might be in a nested container. I can post code which searches recursively in nested containers, but it's in C#. Would you mind?

Comment: Taosique, I appreciate your suggestion but I'm a beginner in VBA, C# would be beyond me! There must be a VBA action that searches at deeper levels? Or by class? My ultimate aim is to loop refresh through the page until it finds a particular element and acts on that element. Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState do not always wait, so I thought, I'd search for the exact element

Comment: Can you share the link or viewsource of document?

Comment: @Santosh, this is part of VBA which isn't waiting for'ssoLoginFrom_0', which is the elementID of the Sign In button: With IE .Visible = True .Navigate "https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do" Do Until .ReadyState = 4 DoEvents Loop .document.all.Item("ssoLoginFrm_0").Click

Comment: @santosh, to clarify, I want VBA to wait until "ssoLoginFrm_0", is found on website "appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
  Sub Login()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do"


    Do While IE.readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    WaitFor 5

    Dim signInButton As Object
    Set signInButton = IE.document.getelementbyid("ssoLoginFrm_0")
    signInButton.Click

End Sub

Sub WaitFor(NumOfSeconds As Long)
    Dim SngSec As Long
    SngSec = Timer + NumOfSeconds

    Do While Timer < SngSec
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: i still need to search. Sometimes, the SignIn button is missing and in that case, I want to exit sub. Configuring your code as follows:  Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do"
    Do While IE.readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Dim signInButton As Object
    Set signInButton = IE.document.getelementbyid("ssoLoginFrm_0")
    If signInButton > 0 Then signInButton.Click Else Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub. I get "end if without block if" error. Why?

Comment: @user2952447 You may add pause of 5 seconds or more as per your requirement so that elements is properly loaded when we try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will post this anyway. I think it wouldn't be hard to refactor this in VBA if you see the logic:

```
public static Control FindAnyControl(this Page page, string controlId)
{
    return FindControlRecursive(page.Form, controlId);
}

public static Control FindAnyControl(this UserControl control, string controlId)
{
    return FindControlRecursive(control, controlId);
}

public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control parent, string controlId)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        Control result = FindControlRecursive(control, controlId);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return parent.FindControl(controlId);
}
```

Then you just call it like this in your page:

```
Control MyControl = new Control();
MyFoundControl = FindControl(this, "MyControlName");
```